Странное поведение абсолютной адресации
есть такой код:
    bits 64
    section .text
    global _start
_start:
    jmp _end
_end:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

при компиляции получается такой
    _start:
0   jmp 2<_end>
    _end:
2   mov eax,0x0
7   ret

тут видно что адресс метки _end это 2
тогда будет логично что jmp 2 будет то же что и jmp _end
    bits 64
    section .text
    global _start
_start:
    jmp 2
_end:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

на при компиляции уже получается совсем другое и код перестаёт работать так как задумывалось:
    _start:
0   jmp 7<end+0x2>
    _end:
5   mov eax,0x0
a   ret

логично что 0 это адресс метки _start, но когда я пишу:
    bits 64
    section .text
    global _start
_start:
    jmp 0
_end:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

то при компиляции получится что 0 это адрес _end:
    _start:
0   jmp 5<_end>
    _end:
5   mov eax,0x0
a   ret

почему так происходит?

Потому что адресация при джампах на метку относительная, а не абсолютная, несмотря на то что вам дизассемблер показывает.

а как сделать абсолютную?

Например, записать текущий адрес в регистр, потом делать переход на адрес в регистре.

вот так? mov rax, $; jmp rax;

Либо пробовать адреса вычислять через $ (текущий адрес), типа jmp $-2 (2 - размер предыдущей команды, заменить на правильный)

Да, пробуйте так

так я уже делал

хорошо, спасибо
